# how to repeat last command in OCaml interpreter shell

Tags: ocaml, interpreter

I've been trying out OCaml. Sometimes its quicker just to test out some code using the interpreter shell but, it doesn't bring up the last command when I press the 'up' key.

Its a pain when I miss type something or wish to see what a little variation would produce.

Anyone know if there is another key for it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `rlwrap`:

```
rlwrap ocaml
```

`ocaml` itself has no readline support.

You can configure readline using `~/.inputrc`.
For example, you could add such lines to it:

```
$if ocaml
"\C-o": "()\C-b"
"\C-n": ";;\n"
$endif
```

Now you can use `ctrl-o` and `ctrl-n` hotkeys in `ocaml`. Just try it.

Comment: There is also `ledit`, which works like rlwrap: `ledit ocaml`. Install with `sudo apt-get install ledit` if you're using Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: cool, ledit was already installed on my ubuntu machine. rlwrap was just as easliy installed with `sudo apt-get install rlwrap` too... is there any benefit in one over the other?

Comment: @neildaemond: I found `rlwrap` better. rlwrap gives you history, filename completion, prompt coloring, syntax completion, brackets matching, use of an external editor and easy configuration via .inputrc.

Comment: Thanks for adding more to your answer, rlwrap it is~ I just added `alias ocaml='rlwrap ocaml'` into my .bashrc :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the improved toplevel [utop](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/utop/).
Moreover, it includes nice completion capacities.

Answer (score 0):

I used ctrl + arrow up for previous input